# Add and remove active class event listener to dynamically generated buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am trying to add active classes such as on hover color change, onclick  have an active color and remain that color on the button as I move forward to click different buttons. I want to remove all these active color on calling remove class. How can I add these active classes to dynamically created buttons? 
[image] this is how buttons appear after adding eventlisteners.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn btn-default', function() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
});

var numOfSets = 1;
var numOfButtons = 10;

for (var j = 0; j < numOfSets; j++) {
  // create the set
  var setElement = "<div style='border: solid 1px red;display:table;width:80%;' id='set" + j + "'>";

  // create its content
  var i = 0;
  for (; i < numOfButtons; i++) {
    var setContent = "<div id='myDIV' class='btn btn-default' style='border:none;background-color: #ccc;border-radius:0;display:table-cell;'></div>";
    // Active classes are added here
    var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default");
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfButtons.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      });
    }
    setElement += setContent;

  }

  //close set div
  setElement += "</div>";
  // append to dom
  $("#areaForSets").append(setElement + "<br/>");
}


/*

    <!--<script>
          $('.btn.btn-default').on("click",function(){ 
                            $(this).addClass('color');                        
         });
         
         $('#Button1').on('click',function() {
          // alert('click');
          $('input:radio[name=options]').each(function () {                                      
             $(this).prop('checked', false);
             $(this).removeClass('color'); 
             $(this).parent().removeClass('color'); 
             $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
          });                  
         });
                      </script> -->
                      */
```

```css
.btn-default {
  color: #D8D8D8;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-color: #D8D8D8;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #5F5A66;
}

.btn-default.active {
  background-color: #4A90E2;
  color: #4A90E2;
  background-color: #4A90E2;
}

.btn-default.color {
  background-color: #4A90E2;
}

.btn-default.focus {
  background-color: #1E3B5D !important;
}

input[type=radio] {
  margin-top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
  <br/>
  <div id="areaForSets">

  </div>
  <div id="myDIV">

  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Haven't really looked at the code, but the first thing I saw was adding `<div id='myDIV'` via `setElement += setContent;`  in a loop. Don't EVER create multiple elements with the same id. It's a recipe for disaster. Element id's must be unique.

Comment: there are couple of issues in this code , first `var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
                var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-default");` will try to get the element from DOM but it will not find it as DOM does not have these elements.Secondly `id` has to be unique

Comment: Plus 2 loops, nested, both using `i`

Comment: Also `numOfButtons.length` ... it's not an array nor a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and your description are not match! I explain what I understand from your question:

**1-on hover color change**
You need to define some events on buttons like below. modify these with your own

```
btn.on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).css('border', '2px solid #5F5A66');
});
btn.on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid #5F9A99');
});
```

**2-onclick have an active color and remain that color on the button as I move forward to click different buttons.**

You need to define `onclick` event with JQuery for each button when you create them. like

```
btn.on('click', function() { 
  $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
});
```

**3-remove all these active color on calling remove class.**

You must loop through all buttons and reset your styles.

```
$("#reset").on('click', function(){
  $('#areaForSets button').each(function(itm) {
    $(this).css({'border': '1px solid #5F9A99'}).removeClass('btn-primary');
  });
})
```

Your final code will be something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn btn-default', function() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
});

var numOfSets = 1;
var numOfButtons = 10;

for (var j = 0; j < numOfSets; j++) {
  // create its content
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++) {
    var setContent = "<button id='myDIV" + i + "' class='btn btn-default'>Test</button>";
    $("#areaForSets").append(setContent);
    // Active classes are added here
    var btn = $("#myDIV" + i);
    btn.addClass("active");
    btn.css('width', `${100/numOfButtons}%`);
    btn.on('click', function() {
      $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
    });
    btn.on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).css('border', '2px solid #5F5A66');
    });
    btn.on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid #5F9A99');
    });
  }
}

$("#reset").on('click', function() {
  $('#areaForSets button').each(function(itm) {
    $(this).css({
      'border': '1px solid #5F9A99'
    }).removeClass('btn-primary');
  });
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <div id="areaForSets">

  </div>
  <button id="reset">Reset All</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for!!

Comment: But only problem is i dont want the div width to change within which buttons are placed. If the number of buttons are 30 it still has to occupy the same width as for 10 buttons.

Comment: in other words, buttons generated should be adaptable to fixed div width.

Comment: Try it now @bhapri